# Need explanation of rtorrent.rc schedule values

Tags: configuration, rtorrent

I want to set-up some watch folders that will then move the completed torrents to a specific directory for further processing. What I would like to know before I proceed based on this rather old guide from [here](http://wiki.rtorrent.org/Recipe/Move%20completed%20torrents%20to%20different%20directory%20depending%20on%20watch%E2%80%A6) is what are the values 11,10 and 12,10 and 13,10? I have done a few searches for this, but haven't been lucky. Maybe my choice of keywords.

```
# Schedules to watch folders
schedule = watch_directory_1,11,10,"load_start=~/torrents/misc/*.torrent,d.set_custom1=~/Downloads/"
schedule = watch_directory_2,12,10,"load_start=~/torrents/tv/*.torrent,d.set_custom1=~/Downloads/TV/"
schedule = watch_directory_3,13,10,"load_start=~/torrents/movie/*.torrent,d.set_custom1=~/Downloads/Movies/"

# Move completed downloads to preset target
system.method.set_key = event.download.finished,move_complete,"d.set_directory=$d.get_custom1=;execute=mv,-u,$d.get_base_path=,$d.get_custom1="
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first value is the start, the second value the interval in which the function is executed. The one seconds difference, just makes sure not all 3 watch_directory "invocations" are distributed over time.

Instead of seconds (as in your example), that can also be time values (HH:MM:SS). The following is scheduled for 1AM every 24 hours:

```
schedule = throttle_1,01:00:00,24:00:00,download_rate=0
schedule = throttle_2,01:00:00,24:00:00,upload_rate=300
```

Comment: When the start value is in seconds what is it in relation to, the start time of rtorrent?

Comment: @alleyoopster I'm not sure if it is the exact start time or some internal base time when certain systems are up internally of rtorrent. Operational that is of little significance, the difference of start times between commands and their interval is more important.